# Replacing the text that follows a given word

Tags: bash, shell, sed, replace, sh

I need help with replacing the first line in the file that follows a given word (which will not be repeated).
I have a file with content:

```
"text1"
{
    "text2" "0"
    "text3" "0"
    "text4" "0"
    "text5" "0"
    "text6" "0"
}
"text11"
{
    "text2" "0"
    "text3" "0"
    "text4" "0"
    "text5" "0"
    "text6" "0"
}
"text21"
{
    "text2" "0"
    "text3" "0"
    "text4" "0"
    "text5" "0"
    "text6" "0"
}
```

I would like to replace in Bash the line containing "text 5.0", but only the first one after the "text11" line.
To finally get the result:

```
"text1"
{
    "text2" "0"
    "text3" "0"
    "text4" "0"
    "text5" "0"
    "text6" "0"
}
"text11"
{
    "text2" "0"
    "text3" "0"
    "text4" "0"
    "REPLACED TEXT" "1"
    "text6" "0"
}
"text21"
{
    "text2" "0"
    "text3" "0"
    "text4" "0"
    "text5" "0"
    "text6" "0"
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: bash, or sh? They're two different shells; which one are you using?

Comment: BTW, your sample input _doesn't_ contain `"text 5.0"` -- it contains `"text5" "0"`, but that's a different string.

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: Also, specify what characters can be inside i.e. `text5`. Or are they always literally the word _text_, followed by a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed '/^"text11"/,/^}/s/"text5" "0"/"REPLACED TEXT" "1"/' file
```

Only in the area with a line starting (`^`) with `"text11"` and the next line starting with `}` replace `"text5" "0"` with `"REPLACED TEXT" "1"`.

Output:

```
"text1"
{
    "text2" "0"
    "text3" "0"
    "text4" "0"
    "text5" "0"
    "text6" "0"
}
"text11"
{
    "text2" "0"
    "text3" "0"
    "text4" "0"
    "REPLACED TEXT" "1"
    "text6" "0"
}
"text21"
{
    "text2" "0"
    "text3" "0"
    "text4" "0"
    "text5" "0"
    "text6" "0"
}
```

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 3):

There is always Perl:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/(^\h*"text11"[\s\S]*?\h*)"text5"\h+"0"/\1"REPLACED TEXT" "1"/m' file
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BXakktaLEUImrmksBCMA8IyUFJQMlBN8YjW@CxjdF45tB@LVcELNpabgRbQxXV7BLy8xJVeDiKkgtylHQNTA3N1fQLUhVUC/W14iLydCC@Sw6pjgmOFbLHiikCTUxJkMbaIZ@jKFSkGuAj6Ozq4tCiGtECNBkQyX9XHUFsMH//wMA)

Answer (score 2):

This is a suitable job for awk.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
  # Before starting, initialize our variables
  BEGIN { arm = 0; done = 0; }

  # The first time we see the text11 section, arm ourselves to look for text5
  /^"text11"$/ && done == 0 {
    arm = 1
  }

  # When we are armed and see text5, perform the replacement, then disarm
  /"text5" "0"/ && arm == 1 {
    done = 1                               # done: ignore any future "text11"
    arm = 0                                # disarm: we are finished
    print("    \"REPLACED TEXT\" \"1\"")   # print our replacement output
    next                                   # do not print $0 for this line
  }

  { print $0 }
'
```

See this running in the online sandbox at https://ideone.com/SyXOjx